# Where does testing fit in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am starting out in Meteor. Coming from Angular world, Just curious, I did not see any kind of testing (TDD) in meteor. Is there something I missed somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, there isn't an officially defined way to do testing in meteor. The best solution I have found is to use the [mocha-web](https://github.com/mad-eye/meteor-mocha-web) package, which gives you client-side testing via the [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) framework with [chai](http://chaijs.com/) assertions. Once you get everything installed you can just define a route on your app (e.g. `/test`) that runs your tests and gives you a nice pass/fail summary. Because it runs on the client, you get the benefit of being able to write tests which use session variables, validation, etc. However, that also means you can't (as far as I know) run something like `make test` and have your results print on the console.

**Update 6/4/2013:**

Here are some more resources you may want to check out:

- [laika](http://arunoda.github.io/laika/)
- [End-to-End Testing for Web Apps](http://blog.xolv.io/2013/04/end-to-end-testing-for-web-apps-meteor.html) and the [presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1nHzs64rDpSbrKrZ0YvQ5iaG26t-XcLCCAGth6Pkr5f4/) from [Devshop 4](http://www.meetup.com/Meteor-SFBay/events/118015502/)

Comment: Also, worth noting that an Official Testing Framework is on the roadmap somewhere down the road after v1.0... Check out the Meteor Roadmap on Trello for updates on it. (https://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae)